# How to set distinct result values in Delphi function?

Tags: delphi, function

I'm coding this function and for the line where I set `result := -10` compiler gives me a warning saying such value is never asigned. Is there something wrong about my logic?

```
function combine (m1, m2 : string) : integer;
var
dash : integer;
distinct : integer;
i : integer;

begin
distinct := 0;
dash := -1;

for i := 0 to Length(m1)-1 do
begin
    if m1[i] = m2[i] then
    begin
      distinct := distinct+1;
      dash := i;
      if distinct > 1 then
          result:= -10;
    end;
end;

result := dash;
end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value is never assigned because you set the value of the `result` to `dash` in the last line.

you can change your code  from

```
  if distinct > 1 then
      result:= -10;
```

to

```
  if distinct > 1 then
      dash:= -10;
```

Comment: I thought I could take setting result in that line to -1 as a *return*

Comment: you need to do `exit;` immediately then, because assigning the `result` does not interrupt the function in Delphi

Comment: What if I want to *exit* with the result value set to -10

Comment: Depending of you version of Delphi you can wrote `if distinct > 1 then begin result:= -10; exit; end;` or `if distinct > 1 then exit(-10);` remember : result is only to set the value of the function and doesn't exit from the method.

Comment: The lack of a return statement and the fact that function results are by var parameters than by value returns, is one of the great design mistakes in Delphi.